# NetSuite SSO only allows map to Admin? Can I switch to a different role?

Tags: web-services, single-sign-on, netsuite

I have managed to get my mapSSO / ssologin working as expected, except I can not seem to use any role other than admin. Is there a way to switch which role you are logged in as or mapped as when using SSO or will it always have to be an admin role?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

inbound SSO can be used for any role, but the key item is that the FIRST mapping in any account MUST be an administrator. Once you have a mapping for an administrator you can set up additional mappings for other users/roles. I'm unsure whether you can map twice for the same user (once as admin, once as a sales person for example).